# JSTL/JSP generate url and force HTTP/HTTPS

Tags: jsp, jstl

I'm using `c:url` to generate my urls relative to the context path.
But all urls will be ***https*** if in a secured page or ***http*** in an unsecured page.
I've set my server so that even if I access for example the login page with http it will redirect to https, but in the login page all the relative urls that I have used will be https.

I want to for example have the homePage link to be http so that it doesn't do a https request and then do another redirect to http !

is there a way to force ***secured(https)*** or ***unsecured(http)*** when generating urls in JSP?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I found to deal with this is use one of the following:

```
http://${pageContext.request.serverName}<c:url value="/my/path"/>
```

or

```
https://${pageContext.request.serverName}<c:url value="/my/path"/>
```

E.g. (in your JSP):

```
You can
<a href="https://${pageContext.request.serverName}<c:url value='/reset-password.jsp'/>">reset your password</a>
if you like.
```

Comment: or `//${pageContext.request.serverName}<c:url value="/my/path"/>`

Comment: Won't this use the protocol of the current page, whatever it is? OP want to *force* the protocol to http or https.

Comment: Point taken, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: This works but I've found that I also had to hardcode the 8443 port (I guess that's because I was not using the default production port of 443)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the generated HTML from the c:url you'll see they are like 
This does not tell you from which host or by what protocol this resource will come, but your browser will take the same host and protocol as the page you are on.

If your page is on http://example.com/mysite and you want to link to subpages on https://secure.example.com/mysite, then this is seen as a link outside your current webapp (even though the code behind that link will eventually be treated by the same webapp). Treat them as you would do for linking to other external sites.